# How to store static files in memory cache

Tags: html, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-devtools, browser-cache

1.[image]

In my case .js files are taken from disk cache and anyway it takes pretty big time.

2.[image]

But on some another project I notices .js and other static files are taken form memory cache.
How can I achieve the same?

Comment: It's not customizable, the browser decides it automatically. Also, don't forget the OS caches frequently used files in memory anyway. And take a look at the resource waterfall in Timeline/Performance panel: there might be other files loaded/parsed/compiled in parallel.

Comment: Can you show us actual requests? You can use Chrome DevTools [Copy All as HAR](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#copy) feature, [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or any other web development tool. Also, please make sure that you disabled all extensions before performing measurements. Check [Chrome slow to load resources (from disk cache)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391256/chrome-slow-to-load-resources-from-disk-cache/42396048#42396048) discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Set **Response Header** in Response from server to

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
```